# Is the completion of a Dedekind domain a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

Ths is a basic question on Dedekind domains.

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $P$ a non-zero prime ideal of $R$. I know that the localization $R_P$ is a PID, but is it true that the completion $\hat{R}_P$ wrt the valuation $v_P$ induced by $P$ is also a PID?

A proof (or a counterexample) or references will be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Yes, it still has only one maximal ideal, so any element of valuation 1 generates the maximal ideal, and all others are powers of that.

Comment: @Adam: Being local is not a sufficient condition to be a pid: the key point is that the completion is still a discrete valuation ring.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, I was indicating the DVR necessity when I was referencing the valuation and how it stays the same (i.e. so that the DVR structure is preserved). That could have been clearer, though, thanks for making it explicit!